# Create Record using Headers from a .csv

Tags: powershell, csv

<EDIT: I kind of have it working, but in order to get it to work, my template csv has to have a blank line for every line I am going to be adding to it. So, if I could figure out how to add lines to the imported empty (just a header row) csv file, I could then use export-csv at the end. (It would be somewhat slower, but it would at least work.)>

I am creating a .csv file in PowerShell. The output file has 140 columns. Many of them are null.

I started out just doing

```
    $out = 'S-'+$Snum+',,,,,TRUE,,,,,'+'S-'+$Snum+',"'
    $out = $out + '{0:d9}' -f $item.SupplierCode2
```

until I had filled all the columns with the correct value. But, the system that is reading the output keeps changing the column locations. So, I wanted to take the header row from the template for the system and use that to name the columns. Then, if the columns change location, it won't matter because I will be referring to it by name.

Because there are so many columns, I'm trying to avoid a solution that has me enter all the column names. By using a blank .csv with just the headers, I can just paste that into the csv whenever it changes and I won't have to change my code.

So, I started by reading my csv file in so I can use the headers.

```
$TempA = Import-Csv -Path $Pathta -Encoding Default
```

Then I was hoping I could do something like this:

```
$TempA.'Supplier Key' = "S-$Snum"
$TempA.'Auto Complete' = "TRUE"
$TempA.'Supplier ID' = "S-$Snum"
$tempA.'Supplier Data - Supplier Reference ID' = '{0:d9}' -f $item.SupplierCode2
```

I would only need to fill in the fields that have values, everything else would be null.
Then I was thinking I could write out this record to a file. My old write looked like this

```
$writer2.WriteLine($out)
```

I wanted to write the line from the new csv line instead

```
$writer2.WriteLine($TempA)
```

I'd rather use streams if I can because the files are large and using add-Content really slows things down.

I know I need to do something to add a line to $TempA and I would like each loop to start with a new line (with all nulls) because there are times when certain lines only have a small subset of the values populated.

Clearly, I'm not taking the correct approach here. I'd really appreciate any advice anyone can give me.

Thank you.

Comment: I commend to your attention the [`Import-CSV`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7.2) and [`Export-CSV`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7.2) cmdlets.

Comment: What's the relationship between the column names in the template file and the one you're creating? How do you know that `Supplier Key` is to be renamed to `S-$Snum`?

Comment: Hi @MathiasR.Jessen, Supplier Key is the header on the csv file that I need to build. Right now, that is the first column in the csv, but in some future time, it could be second or third or whatever, but it will always have the column header of 'Supplier Key'. S-$Snum is the value that needs to be in the 'Supplier Key' column of the csv on every line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to fill in certain fields, and don't mind using `Export-Csv` you can use the `-append` and `-force` switches, and it will put the properties in the right places. For example, if you had the template CSV file with only the column names in it you could do:

```
$Output = ForEach($item in $allItems){
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Supplier Key' = "S-$Snum"
        'Auto Complete' = "TRUE"
        'Supplier ID' = "S-$Snum"
        'Supplier Data - Supplier Reference ID' = '{0:d9}' -f $item.SupplierCode2
    }
}
$Output | Export-Csv -Path $Pathta -Append -Force
```

That would create objects with only the four properties that you are interested in, and then output them to the CSV in the correct columns, adding commas as needed to create blank values for all other columns.

Comment: what if I need to do other logic in the loop? Something like an if statement to provide a different value depending on the values of the input. (Formatting zip codes for example requires a fair amount of logic when the previous system allowed any format to be used.)

Comment: Then do that. This was really just a simple example that you can generate objects with a specific limited set of properties, and then output them to a CSV with more columns.

Comment: Thank you. This will work for what I am trying to do.